# Optional function parameter in firestore.rules

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a function in my rules to check if a given field is not set or not set incorrectly upon creation:

```
function isNotInitializingField(fieldName, defaultValue) {
  return resource == null && !(request.resource.data.keys().hasAny([fieldName]) || request.resource.data[fieldName] == defaultValue);
}
```

Which causes all calls without a default value to create a warning:

> WARNING Incorrect number of arguments supplied to function: isNotInitializingField.

**I would like to suppress this WARNING and eventually following errors by listing the parameter as optional.**

I have 2 possible solutions to fix it the dirty way:

One would be to split the functions and call them with a "or" to have one check for `initializingFieldWithDefaultValue` and `notInitializingField`

The other one would be to use an array as parameter and supply at index 0 the field name and in applicable cases at index 1 the default value, which then could be checked inside the function and not cause a WARNING.

Is there a proper solution or shall i deploy my workarounds?

Answer (score 1):

The array option seems more suitable. It is easy to understand and if you need to scale it in the future, it is easy to do.
Example below:

```
function isNotInitializingField(args) {
  const fieldName = args[0];
  const defaultValue = args[1];
  return resource == null && (request.resource.data.keys().hasAny([fieldName]) || request.resource.data[fieldName] == defaultValue);
}
```